# Swift: How to get one item from shuffled array

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

I created an array of words and I shuffled it.
I added a button and I want it to print one of the randomisers words in the array in a label. I know how to do that with integers but with stings it seems to be different. How can I do?
This is my code:

```
IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!


IBAction getText(_ sender: Any) {
        let words = textView.text.components.shuffled()
        print (words)
}
```

I thought I had to add in my button something like

```
label.text = words
```

But

1. It says it can't convert [String] to string
2. It prints all of the words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
label.text = words.first ?? "No words"
```

or

```
label.text = words.randomElement() ?? "No words"
```

`words` is an array of type `String` so you can't assign it directly to the `text` property of the label which is of type `String`

Comment: The use of the `?? ""` nil coalescing operator there is pointless. `UILabel`s `text` property is declared as optional String `String?` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text.  Both `label.text = words.first` and `label.text = words.randomElement()` would suffice

Comment: @LeoDabus Although the text property is optional, this answer is the correct way. If the text property is nil on the UILabel after assigning text to it, something is very wrong. Without the ?? "No words", the UILabel's text is just empty when the words array doesn't have elements, something that just looks weird to the user I think...

Comment: @J.Doe `UILabel`'s `text` property is nil by default. I don't see any advantage setting it to an empty string instead of leaving it nil. `"No words"` was added after my comment.

Comment: @LeoDabus A yes, `?? ""` would be pointless indeed :) didn't know the "No words" was added later